# using redux-persist with redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, redux-persist

Hey guys i was using redux thunk with nextjs and now i want to add redux-persist in my app. So initially my code is like

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from './reducers';

export const makeStore = (initialState, options) => {
    return createStore(reducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
};
```

can anyone help me with only in the setup with redux persist now ? I have tried some solution but didnt worked out

Answer (score 16):

If you really need to persist your `redux state` there are two options as far as I know:
first you could use `react-persist` as per your wish like this

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from './reducers';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'reducer',
    storage: storage,
    whitelist: ['reducer'] // or blacklist to exclude specific reducers
 };
const presistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer );
const store = createStore(presistedReducer, 
composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export { persistor, store };
```

and then in your `component` you do the following as instructed in their `documentation`

```
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

// ... normal setup, create store and persistor, import components etc.

const App = () => {
return (
   <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <RootComponent />
      </PersistGate>
   </Provider>
  );
};
```

or you could simply do the following `without relying on a library`

```
import {
  createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware,
 } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from './reducers';
function saveToLocalStorage(state) {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
}

function loadFromLocalStorage() {
const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
if (serializedState === null) return undefined;
   return JSON.parse(serializedState);
}

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const presistedState = loadFromLocalStorage();
const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    presistedState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)),
 );
store.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(store.getState()));
export default store;
```

Comment: so the state will be set to localstorage  every time i call an action creater and reducer perform some mutation ? i mean if some inital state is stored and then after sometime i again update the state so that updated state would be again save to local ?

Comment: yes, you get to persist the piece of state you desire in `storage`, you can pass your `initial state` as a default value for the state argument in your `reducer function`, and then after every change your state updates should be persisted.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  As far as redux devtools goes, will it be hidden from production the way it's written here? Or does it need more conditional logic to hide it if process.env === "production" for example?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [link of the article](https://medium.com/@dharacharolap/get-rid-of-data-consistency-with-the-redux-persist-86559e96de32) having simple but detailed steps to integrate & use the package in your existing app.

Usually, I follow the same structure that you have for the redux store. This integration always works for me. So I hope this will help you out too.